# Split a numpy array using masking in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array `my_array` of size `100x20`. I want to create a function that receives as an input a 2d numpy array `my_arr` and an index `x` and will return two arrays one with size `1x20` `test_arr` and one with `99x20` `train_arr`. The vector `test_arr` will correspond to the row of the matrix `my_arr` with the index `x` and the `train_arr` will contain the rest rows. I tried to follow a solution using masking:

```
def split_train_test(my_arr, x):

   a = np.ma.array(my_arr, mask=False)
   a.mask[x, :] = True
   a = np.array(a.compressed())
   return a
```

Apparently this is not working as i wanted. How can i return a numpy array as a result and the train and test arrays properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use simple index and [`numpy.delete`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html) for this:

```
def split_train_test(my_arr, x):
    return np.delete(my_arr, x, 0), my_arr[x:x+1]

my_arr = np.arange(10).reshape(5,2)

train, test = split_train_test(my_arr, 2)

train
#array([[0, 1],
#       [2, 3],
#       [6, 7],
#       [8, 9]])

test
#array([[4, 5]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a boolean index as the mask:

```
def split_train_test(my_arr, x):

    # define mask
    mask=np.zeros(my_arr.shape[0], dtype=bool)
    mask[x] = True # True only at index x, False elsewhere

    return my_arr[mask, :], my_arr[~mask, :]
```

Sample run:

```
test_arr, train_arr = split_train_test(np.random.rand(100, 20), x=10)

print(test_arr.shape, train_arr.shape)
((1L, 20L), (99L, 20L))
```

---

**EDIT:**

If someone is looking for the general case where more than one element needs to be allocated to the test array (say 80%-20% split), `x` can also accept an array:

```
my_arr = np.random.rand(100, 20)
x = np.random.choice(np.arange(my_arr.shape[0]), int(my_arr .shape[0]*0.8), replace=False)

test_arr, train_arr = split_train_test(my_arr, x)
print(test_arr.shape, train_arr.shape)
((80L, 20L), (20L, 20L))
```